# Jenkins jobs says build success but scripts in testng.xml are not executing

Tags: maven, jenkins

I created a sample maven project and i have a class with below code

```
package Basics;    
import org.testng.annotations.Test;  

public class Second {

    @Test
    public void jenkinstest()
    {
        System.out.println("Jenkins test sample");
    }
}
```

and below is the testng.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE suite SYSTEM "http://testng.org/testng-1.0.dtd">
<suite name="Suite">
<test thread-count="5" name="Test">
<classes>
<class name="Basics.Second"/>
</classes>
</test> <!-- Test -->
</suite> <!-- Suite -->
```

I create a maven project in Jenkins and provided above project pom.xml path in Root pom field, then when i click on "BuildNow", Jenkins jobs says build success but scripts in testng.xml are not executing

Below is the output from Jenkins

```
Started by user anonymous
Building in workspace C:\Users\manchukondaanil_k\.jenkins\workspace\JenkinsRun
Parsing POMs
[Guru99] $ "C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_73/bin/java" -cp C:\Users\manchukondaanil_k\.jenkins\plugins\maven-plugin\WEB-INF\lib\maven31-agent-1.5.jar;D:\Selenium_Softwares\apache-maven-3.2.5\boot\plexus-classworlds-2.5.2.jar;D:\Selenium_Softwares\apache-maven-3.2.5/conf/logging jenkins.maven3.agent.Maven31Main D:\Selenium_Softwares\apache-maven-3.2.5 C:\Users\manchukondaanil_k\.jenkins\war\WEB-INF\lib\remoting-2.56.jar C:\Users\manchukondaanil_k\.jenkins\plugins\maven-plugin\WEB-INF\lib\maven31-interceptor-1.5.jar C:\Users\manchukondaanil_k\.jenkins\plugins\maven-plugin\WEB-INF\lib\maven3-interceptor-commons-1.5.jar 52811
<===[JENKINS REMOTING CAPACITY]===>channel started
Executing Maven:  -B -f D:\SeleniumProjects\Guru99Project\Guru99\pom.xml clean install
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
[INFO]                                                                         
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Building Guru99 0.0.1-SNAPSHOT
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-clean-plugin:2.5:clean (default-clean) @ Guru99 ---
[INFO] Deleting D:\SeleniumProjects\Guru99Project\Guru99\target
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-resources-plugin:2.6:resources (default-resources) @ Guru99 ---
[INFO] Using 'UTF-8' encoding to copy filtered resources.
[INFO] skip non existing resourceDirectory D:\SeleniumProjects\Guru99Project\Guru99\src\main\resources
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-compiler-plugin:3.1:compile (default-compile) @ Guru99 ---
[INFO] Changes detected - recompiling the module!
[INFO] Compiling 2 source files to D:\SeleniumProjects\Guru99Project\Guru99\target\classes
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-resources-plugin:2.6:testResources (default-testResources) @ Guru99 ---
[INFO] Using 'UTF-8' encoding to copy filtered resources.
[INFO] skip non existing resourceDirectory D:\SeleniumProjects\Guru99Project\Guru99\src\test\resources
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-compiler-plugin:3.1:testCompile (default-testCompile) @ Guru99 ---
[INFO] Nothing to compile - all classes are up to date
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-surefire-plugin:2.4.3:test (default-test) @ Guru99 ---
[INFO] No tests to run.
[JENKINS] Recording test results
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-jar-plugin:2.4:jar (default-jar) @ Guru99 ---
[INFO] Building jar: D:\SeleniumProjects\Guru99Project\Guru99\target\Guru99-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-install-plugin:2.4:install (default-install) @ Guru99 ---
[INFO] Installing D:\SeleniumProjects\Guru99Project\Guru99\target\Guru99-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar to C:\Users\manchukondaanil_k\.m2\repository\Guru99\Guru99\0.0.1-SNAPSHOT\Guru99-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar
[INFO] Installing D:\SeleniumProjects\Guru99Project\Guru99\pom.xml to C:\Users\manchukondaanil_k\.m2\repository\Guru99\Guru99\0.0.1-SNAPSHOT\Guru99-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.pom
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD SUCCESS
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 9.957 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2018-03-28T15:54:07+05:30
[INFO] Final Memory: 24M/181M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
Waiting for Jenkins to finish collecting data
[JENKINS] Archiving D:\SeleniumProjects\Guru99Project\Guru99\pom.xml to Guru99/Guru99/0.0.1-SNAPSHOT/Guru99-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.pom
[JENKINS] Archiving D:\SeleniumProjects\Guru99Project\Guru99\target\Guru99-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar to Guru99/Guru99/0.0.1-SNAPSHOT/Guru99-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar
channel stopped
Finished: SUCCESS
```

Comment: You should name your tests accordingly the convention something like `XYZTest.java` and put them into correct location `src/test/java`...

Comment: Yes my class name is Second.java and i have this code in src/main/java and i could able to see results when i ran testng.xml directly from eclipse. so will it make difference if test present in src/main/java instead of src/test/java ?

Comment: If this a test class it has to be in src/test/java and you should name it accordingly and yes it makes a difference cause test will be executed the code in src/main/java will not...but will run your tests so you have to put them into src/test/java

Comment: I created a new class in src/test/java and modified testng.xml accordingly then when i ran it from Jenkins this time I see following message There are no tests to run.
Results :
Tests run: 0, Failures: 0, Errors: 0, Skipped: 0

Comment: Please make a test project  on Gitbub..which shows the problematic behaviour...

Comment: You need to specify your testng.xml that needs to be trigerred.  Just making the testng.xml doesn't help.  If you do not want the xml to be used then you need to do what @khmarbaise is pointing to - naming convention of file matters.

Comment: @niharika_neo where i need to specify my testng.xml ? in jenkins or some where else

Comment: In your pom - surefire plugin section.

Comment: @niharika_neo Thanks it helped by keeping testng.xml details in pom

Comment: Putting as an answer then to close this

Answer (score 0):

You need to specify your testng.xml in your surefire section of pom.xml, that this is the testng suite that needs to be trigerred. Just making the testng.xml doesn't help. If you do not want the xml to be used then you need to do what @khmarbaise is pointing to - naming convention of file matters.